# How to unpivot a single row in Oracle 11?

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

I have a row of data and I want to turn this row into a column so I can use a cursor to run through the data one by one. I have tried to use

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PIVOT(TEMPROW))
```

but I get

> 'PIVOT' Invalid Identifier error.

I have also tried that same syntax but with

```
('select * from TEMPROW')
```

Everything I see using pivot is always using count or sum but I just want this one single row of all varchar2 to turn into a column.

My row would look something like this:

ABC | 123 | aaa | bbb | 111 | 222 |

And I need it to turn into this:

ABC

123

aaa

bbb

111

222

My code is similar to this:

```
BEGIN
    OPEN C_1 FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(PIVOT( 'SELECT * FROM TEMPROW'));
        LOOP
            FETCH C_1 INTO TEMPDATA;
            EXIT WHEN C_2%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(1);
         END LOOP;
    CLOSE C_1;
END;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option for `unpivoting` would be numbering columns by `decode()` and `cross join` with the query containing the column numbers :

```
select decode(myId, 1, col1,
                    2, col2,
                    3, col3,
                    4, col4,
                    5, col5,
                    6, col6 ) as result_col
  from temprow
  cross join (select level AS myId FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 6 );
```

or use a query with `unpivot` keyword by considering the common expression for the column ( namely `col` in this case ) must have same datatype as corresponding expression :

```
select result_col from
(
select col1, to_char(col2) as col2, col3, col4, 
       to_char(col5) as col5, to_char(col6) as col6  
  from temprow
 ) 
 unpivot (result_col for col in (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6));
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c873e116f144aac9dfc7b05397319975)</kbd>

Comment: I guess union is much better than a cross join but either way both are correct

Comment: well, seems you need to cast the columns to a string type for the numeric type columns :), btw I hate excessive `union`  @HimanshuAhuja

Comment: Yeah casting is required in cases for numerics though that was a sample i posted. Nevermind, OP has marked your post as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to unpivot to convert whole row into 1 single column

```
     select * from Table
     UNPIVOT
     (col for col in (
       'ABC' , '123' , 'aaa' ,' bbb' , '111' , '222' 
       ))
```

or use union but for that you need to add col names manually like

```
Select * from ( Select col1 from table 
 union
 select col2 from table union...
 Select coln from table)
```

sample output to show as below

[image]

Comment: Do i need to list the exact values each time? Because they are generated on runtime depending on the parameter I give. I do however know the column names, would that work?

Comment: Then you can have select * after unpivot

Comment: Both pivot and unpivot appear black as if they were variables, which is leading me to believe my Oracle doesn't support them. I am running Oracle 11.2.

Comment: Then you have to use union but that would be manual like select col1 from table union select col2 from table..... Union select coln from table